Does customtkinter have an implementation similar to indicatoron of RadioButtons?
Good day,
I'm a long-time Tkinter developer and I'm starting to learn customtkinter. However, I'm not able to find a customtkinter RadioButton argument that is similar to that of the indicatoron present in the old tkinter library.
Thanks.

You may try CTkSegmentedButton.

Can't you use a normal button when you want indicatoron to be False ?
